# Getting HTML select dropdowns to render on a mobile

Tags: html, css, forms

I am having trouble getting a form to work on a mobile, because I am unable to select the dropdowns.

I have resorted to taking out all the styles, in an attempt to render a basic form, but this still hasn't worked. Here is the HTML:

```
        <label>
            <span>Options</span>
            <select id="options" >
                <option value="">Select an option</option>
                <option value="option1">option 1</option>
                <option value="option2">option 2</option>
            </select>
            <span class="errors" id="optionsError">Please select an option</span>
            <br />
        </label>
```

and the only styles associated with it are:

```
margin-top: 80px;margin-bottom: 80px;height: 50px;
```

which were put in place, because I had a hunch that there wasn't enough space for the dropdown to be clicked.

Has anyone else had a similar issue?

Comment: In what way are you unable to 'select the drop-downs'? What are you trying to achieve *by* selecting the drop-downs?

Comment: Well I can't seem to press it with my thumb on a mobile. It will either do nothing or simply select the field nearby. I have just about got it to recognize a thumb press but I can't change its value still

Answer (score 0):

How I solve this is by changing the fon't size. That will automatically make the drop down larger. So my css looks like this

```
.drop{
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 2em;
  width:80%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's getting there, but now the value doesn't seem to change when I select option 2. Option 1 is still shown as the selected choice.

Comment: I see why! <option value="option1">option 2</option> change the value to option2 :)

Comment: Lol sorry to bring you down but that's a typo on SO and not in my code.. You got me excited for a second!

Comment: So both options are submitting as option1? Are you handling this with PHP as a backend?

Comment: no option one has the value "option 1" and option 2 has the value "option 2". I don't think that is the problem, its the phone not activating the dropdown functionality. I am building a Spring project, so handling it in Java

Comment: What phone are you working on? Because, I just did something like this and on my iPhone I didn't have to do anything, but make sure the options were correct. Here's a pic of selecting an option http://i1280.photobucket.com/albums/a485/Jessica_Sears/image_zpsc1382e99.png

Comment: I am using a desire S, but my mate couldn't work it on his samsumg galaxy either. I am wondering if there are containers or spans blocking the fields. Here is an example with no styles at all:http://james.ivings.name:28029/NorthSomersetTraders/traders.htm

Comment: Well, I do have some good news. It works fine on my iphone. I would google and see of there are some known bugs with drop downs and those phones. I know when I built my last iphone app, I had to incorporate many different hacks for many different phones. May I suggest trying to make your whole website responsive either by media queries or something like toast.css. That would make your like simpler in the long run and you wont run into things like this.

Comment: Oh that is good news! Maybe its just the odd phone then. This site wasn't intended for all phones and is really a desktop project, so I think I will leave the tweaks for now. I have been rushed with this project so there are a lot of things I need to tidy up. Thanks for the advice and testing :)